# Redirect only current page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to redirect from Vue.js with mounted, but it updates me all the pages. I am using broadcasting with laravel and view with vue. From an administrator screen, I validate user data, and it works fine, but it redirects my current view. Why is this happening?

**Admin controller**

```php
public function cambiarEstado($estado, $id)
{
    Acceso::where('id', $id)->update(['estado' => $estado]);

    // Usamos broadcast
    $message = 'Usuario verificado!';
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    event(new ChatEvent ($message, $user));

    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

**Vue**

```
mounted(){
    Echo.private('my-chat')
    .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
        window.location.href = '/mails';
    });
}
```

The code updates the admin view and the user view. I want to redirect the user, not the administrator.

```
window.location.href = '/mails';
```